# Show help block on the top of the page

Tags: feature-request, design

Vertical position of the help block while [asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (or for [markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)) is on the top by default:

> [image: top]

But if you slightly scroll page down this block jumps to the (approx) middle of the screen:

> [image: middle]

**Is it possible to prevent such jumping and hold block on the top while scrolling?**

Moreover it could reduce a size of ugly overlapped area with footer when scrolling to the bottom occurs:

> [image: bottom]